# sum of rows using sqlserver

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using sqlserver, which has following table ,

```
id    companyname     credited      used
----------------------------------------
1       ABC             100          0
2       ABC             10           0
3       BBB              0           10
4       BBB              0           10
5       BBB             100           0
6       BBB             10            0
```

My expected output as below

```
id    companyname     credited      used      sum_credited    sum_used
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
1       ABC             100          0         110              0
2       ABC             10           0         110              0
3       BBB              0           10         0               20
4       BBB              0           10         0               20
5       BBB             100           0        110              0
6       BBB             10            0        110              0
```

I have used the below query in which i didnt get as espected output

```
SELECT id,companyname,Credited,Used, SUM(credited) 'Sum_Credited'  
FROM tmptichistory1 
GROUP BY id,companyname,Credited,Used
```

I want to find the sum of credited and used values and display it in different columns with original values as i mentioned in the first table. Any help is appreciable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sum group by companyname`;

Mistake (thanks `@bluefeet`) corrected with a `CASE` [here is fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fb977/32):

```
;with cte as
(
  select companyname, sum(credited) sum_credited, sum(used) sum_used
  from tmptichistory1
  group by companyname
)
select t1.id, t1.companyname, t1.credited, t1.used, 
 case t1.credited when 0 then 0 else cte.sum_credited end sum_credited,
 case t1.used when 0 then 0 else cte.sum_used end sum_used
from tmptichistory1 t1 join cte
on t1.companyname = cte.companyname
```

Comment: I didn't downvote you but this doesn't give the desired output see this sql fiddle -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fb977/24 -- It puts the sum credited and sum used on each row which is not what the OP initially requested.

Comment: @bluefeet : thanks !!! I have rectified [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fb977/32)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t1.id,
       t2.companyname,
       t1.credited,
       t1.used,
       t2.sum_credited,
       t2.sum_used
  FROM yourTable t1
  INNER JOIN
  (
      SELECT companyname, SUM( credited)  sum_credited , SUM(used) sum_used
        FROM yourTable 
       WHERE credited = 0
       GROUP BY companyname
      UNION
      SELECT companyname, SUM( credited)  sum_credited , SUM(used) sum_used
        FROM yourTable 
       WHERE used = 0
       GROUP BY companyname
  ) t2 ON t1.companyname = t2.companyname
  WHERE (t1.used = 0 AND t2.sum_used = 0) OR (t1.credited = 0 AND t2.sum_credited = 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one it may help you..

```
select e1.Id,e1.CompanyNmae, e1.credited, e1.used,e2.SumCredited,e2.SumUsed  
from Example e1
inner join (select CompanyNmae, sum(credited) as SumCredited, sum(used) as SumUsed 
     from Example group by CompanyNmae) as e2
  on e1.CompanyNmae=e2.CompanyNmae
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using 2008 version or later, you can use analytic functions like this:

```
select 
id,
companyname,
credited,
used,
sum(credited) over (partition by companyname) sum_credited,
sum(used) over (partition by companyname) sum_used

from
tmptichistory1
```

But when I run it against your data I get the following output:

```
+----+-------------+----------+------+--------------+----------+
| id | companyname | credited | used | sum_credited | sum_used |
+----+-------------+----------+------+--------------+----------+
|  1 | ABC         |      100 |    0 |          110 |        0 |
|  2 | ABC         |       10 |    0 |          110 |        0 |
|  3 | BBB         |        0 |   10 |          110 |       20 |
|  4 | BBB         |        0 |   10 |          110 |       20 |
|  5 | BBB         |      100 |    0 |          110 |       20 |
|  6 | BBB         |       10 |    0 |          110 |       20 |
+----+-------------+----------+------+--------------+----------+
```

... so i think your rows with id = 5 and id = 6 should perhaps be for a different companyname? If we say companyname CCC then we get the following output:

```
+----+-------------+----------+------+--------------+----------+
| id | companyname | credited | used | sum_credited | sum_used |
+----+-------------+----------+------+--------------+----------+
|  1 | ABC         |      100 |    0 |          110 |        0 |
|  2 | ABC         |       10 |    0 |          110 |        0 |
|  3 | BBB         |        0 |   10 |            0 |       20 |
|  4 | BBB         |        0 |   10 |            0 |       20 |
|  5 | CCC         |      100 |    0 |          110 |        0 |
|  6 | CCC         |       10 |    0 |          110 |        0 |
+----+-------------+----------+------+--------------+----------+
```

Which looks more like what you have in your example.